Multi Label Classification - Keras
I am working on a multi digit classification of MNIST Data set , each image got 3 digits , i managed to upload the images and identify the classes. I am using CNN model for classification but getting very low accuracy .
#Generators to create the data into small batches for large data
train_dataset = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory= train_path,
    labels ='inferred',
    label_mode ='int',
    class_names=None,
    batch_size = 32,
    image_size= (IMG_ROWS,IMG_COLS),
    color_mode='grayscale')

Found 64000 files belonging to 640 classes.

valid_dataset = keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory= val_path,
    labels ='inferred',
    label_mode ='int',
    class_names=None,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    image_size= (IMG_ROWS,IMG_COLS)
)

Found 16000 files belonging to 160 classes.
model =Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size= (5,5) , activation ='relu', input_shape= INPUT_SHAPE))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2, padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size= (5,5) , activation ='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2, padding='valid'))


 # converting data into a 1D array for inputting it to the next layer.Flatten the output of convolutional layers to create a single
 #long feature vector and will connect to final classificaiton model named as fully connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32,activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(640,activation ='softmax'))

model.compile(Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=30, validation_data= valid_dataset, callbacks=[es], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=1)```
I  would expect the accuracy to be around 60 percent but even executing it for 15 epochs i am not getting the 50% accuracy 
Not sure that i am missing anything , would appreciate your help 


